# Buscar palabra escondida con regex

Tags: java, regex, string

Estoy tratando de buscar una palabra oculta con regex, pero no entiendo porqué mi código no funciona.

```
String s = "ahwereovnkejfnlvienfvia";
String regex = "[a-z]h[a-z]o[a-z]l[a-z]a[a-z]";
String regex2 = ".h.o.l.a."
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Mi objetivo es saber si el string contiene oculta entre los caracteres la palabra "hola", pero siempre me dice que no.

La lógica que estoy tratando de usar es:

- cualquier caracter delante o detrás de los caracteres de la palabra que busco.
- no sé conoce cuantos caracteres hay delante ni detrás de cada letra de la palabra oculta.

Comment: Que caracteres pueden haber entre letra y letra? Cualquiera? Tanto especiales como numeros y letras?

Comment: Sí, puede ser cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La expresión regular que has definido no se adecua al problema que intentas resolver ya que:

- permite la existencia de un único carácter antes de cada letra de la palabra `"hola"`
- los caracteres entre palabras no son opcionales

Solo matchearia strings que cumplan dichas condiciones, como por ejemplo `1h2o3l4a5`

Lo que necesitas es una expresión regular que permita que existan **0 o más caracteres entre las letras** y eso lo puedes lograr con `.*`

`.*` es análogo a utilizar `.{0,}`, y representa **cualquier caracter, 0 o más veces**.

**La expresión regular a utilizar sería:**

`.*h.*o.*l.*a.*`

En Java puedes definir un método que reciba un string a chequear y una palabra oculta a encontrar y en base a esta ultima construir la expresión regular:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findWord("h_o_l4a$#", "hola")); // true
    System.out.println(findWord("1$h#2o3#l4#a5", "hola")); // true
    System.out.println(findWord("1h2o3l4a5","hola")); // true
    System.out.println(findWord("ha2loa","hola")); // false
    
    System.out.println(findWord("#a$di0os", "adios")); // true
    System.out.println(findWord("ad?i0os1", "adios")); // true
    System.out.println(findWord("1ad1os?","adios")); // false

}

private static boolean findWord(String string, String hiddenWord){
      StringBuilder regex= new StringBuilder(".*");
      for (char c: hiddenWord.toCharArray()) {
            regex.append(c);
            regex.append(".*");
      }
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());
      Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
      return m.matches();
}
```

Comment: Gracias, justamente era esto.